# Deserializing JSON containing single or array of objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to deserialize event data that includes image urls.

When the event includes a single image, the format of the JSON string is:

```
"images": {
  "image": {
      "small": {...},
      "width": "48",
      "creator": null,
      "thumb": {...},
      "height": "48",
      "url": "http://example.com/image1.jpeg",
      "medium": {...},
      "id": "1"
    }
}
```

When multiple images are available, the format of the response changes to:

```
"images": {
    "image": [
      {
        "small": {...},
        "width": "48",
        "creator": null,
        "thumb": {...},
        "height": "48",
        "url": "http://example.com/image1.jpeg",
        "medium": {...},
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "small": {...},
        "width": "48",
        "creator": null,
        "thumb": {...},
        "height": "48",
        "url": "http://example.com/image2.jpeg",
        "medium": {...},
        "id": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I'm trying to deserialize, I can get one or other model to work, but not both at the same time.

My model is something like:

```
public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string imageId { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public int smallId { get; set; }
    public Small small { get; set; }
    public int mediumId { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public int thumbId { get; set; }
    public Thumb thumb { get; set; }
}
```

If I define my Images class as follows, it works with arrays:

```
public class Images
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Image> image { get; set; }
}
```

If I define it as follows, it works with single images:

```
public class Images
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
}
```

In theory, I could contain both a List and an Image in the Images class, but I can't use the same name for both and the deserialization doesn't work if I change either name.

I understand that both responses are valid JSON (they represent what they're supposed to), but is this a bad implementation?

Or am I missing something in my model/deserialization that should allow me to deserialize both the single object and array?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Deserialization code:

```
var feedUrl = url;
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EventDetail));

var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(feedUrl);
EventDetail eventDetail = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as EventDetail;

return eventDetail;
```

Comment: Please post your serialization/deserialization   code as well. May it will help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Similar question was asked in the past: "[How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)". The approach is basically to use customConverter as follow:

```
public class Images
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Image>))]
    public List<Image> Image { get; set; }
}


public class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hsoesanto - that is exactly the same issue. I didn't find it when I searched.

Comment: Although wouldn't the Image definition should be as follows:

public class Images
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]
    public List<Image> Image { get; set; }
}

Comment: @PaulM Sorry, you are right. Missed that when editing it before. It is fixed now. Glad it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your serialization/deserialization code I think the problem is there.

One other Solution could be that you send an empty list of Images (`Images`) if you only have one `Image` and the other way around. So you always have `Image`and `Images` in your JSON.